# Let $S_1$ and $S_2$ be convex sets. Show that the intersection $S_1 \cap S_2$ is a convex set

Tags: linear-algebra

Found this exercise in "Introduction to Linear Algebra" by Serge Lang. It says:

"Let $S_1$ and $S_2$ be convex sets. Show that the intersection $S_1 \cap S_2$ is a convex set"

My process is as follows:

Let $A = (a_1, a_2), B = (b_1, b_2) \in S_1 \cap S_2$ which means that

- $A, B \in S_1$
- $A, B \in S_2$

The line between them is

$$\begin{aligned}
    (1-t)A + tB &= (1-t)(a_1, a_2) + t(b_1, b_2) \\
                &= ((1-t)a_1 + tb_1, (1-t)a_2 + tb_2)
\end{aligned}$$

I know that I should manipulate this expression to get one that is clearly both in $S_1$ and in $S_2$ and thus in $S_1 \cap S_2$ but I don't know what else I could do with it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $A,B \in S_1$, then $(1-t)A + tB \in S_1$

Since $A,B \in S_2$, then $(1-t)A + tB \in S_2$

Hence  $(1-t)A + tB$, which is the convex combiantion, belongs to the intersection.

Answer (score 2):

This is easier than trying to compute the actual line segment. Let $l$ be a line segment between $s_1,s_2\in S_1\cap S_2$. Since both points are in $S_1$ all points in $l$ are in $S_1$. Likewise for $S_2$ so the line segment is contained in the intersection.

Since this is true for all such pairs of points, the intersection is convex.

Answer (score 0):

In general, for **any** collection of convex sets $\{C_\alpha\}$, the set $C = \cap_\alpha C_\alpha $ is convex.

If $x,y \in C$ and $\lambda \in [0,1]$, then $x,y \in C_\alpha$ for all $\alpha$ and so for any $\alpha$ we have $\lambda x+ (1-\lambda)y \in C_\alpha$ and hence $\lambda x+ (1-\lambda)y \in C$.